# How can radio radiation ionize gases?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, plasma-physics, ionization-energy

Reading the operational mechanism of [Variable Specific Impulse Magnetoplasma Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_Specific_Impulse_Magnetoplasma_Rocket) (VASIMR) on Wikipedia, I encountered the following:

> The propellant, a neutral gas such as argon or xenon, is injected into a hollow cylinder... bombards the gas with electromagnetic energy, at a frequency of 10 to 50 MHz, stripping electrons off the propellant atoms and producing a plasma of ions and free electrons

How is this possible? To strip the electron of a noble gas such as argon requires electromagnetic radiation at frequencies in the GHz range. How is it ionized then?

Answer (score 3):

The full quote  in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_Specific_Impulse_Magnetoplasma_Rocket) is

> "the gas is first **heated** to a “cold plasma” by a helicon RF antenna/couple  that bombards the gas with electromagnetic energy, at a frequency of 10 to 50 MHz, stripping electrons off the propellant atoms and producing a plasma of ions and free electrons."

bold mine.

The  radiation heats the gas, which means transfers kinetic energy to the atoms. The energy distribution of the atoms of the heated gas will have a high kinetic energy tail which allows through scatterings between atoms  to ionize the atoms.

Comment: Why do you mention infrared radiation? 10-50 MHz is not normally considered infrared radiation (https://www.britannica.com/science/infrared-radiation).

Comment: @akhmeteli by everyday maning of heat. you are correct , it is only the process of heating that is used, i.e raising the temperature of the gas. I will edit

Comment: "The radiation heats the gas, which means transfers kinetic energy to the atoms." My understanding is different. If it is not multi-photon ionization, but avalanche ionization, initial random free electrons are accelerated in the field, a combination of this acceleration and collisions with atoms increases kinetic energy of these electrons, and eventually they are able to ionize atoms and start an avalanche.

Comment: @akhmeteli reading the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_Specific_Impulse_Magnetoplasma_Rocket#Design_and_operation  I interpret it differently. after all there are no "free electrons" to start with in the initial gas.

Comment: I don't find confirmation of your reading in that article. You may look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law#Physical_mechanism , the gas discharge mechanism at radio frequency is pretty much the same. There are always some initial electrons (for example, from cosmic rays), but some external source of electrons can be used as well for stable discharge.

Answer (score 1):

A strong enough electromagnetic field would ionize gas no matter what frequency. It can be avalanche or multiphoton ionization.

Comment: But does this not go against the principles of quantum mechanics. Fundamentally, the ideas of a discrete energy package ("quanta") comes from the discovery in the photoelectric effect that only certain light frequencies would make a material emit electrons, no matter how intense a lesser frequency light be shone.

Comment: What is the theoretical and mathematical background for this. How can one calculate how much energy is required to ionize then?

Comment: @C-Consciousness : "no matter how intense a lesser frequency light be shone" This wording is a simplification. You don't need to believe me on my word. See e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211379715000066 or https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/54/10/002/pdf . I cannot describe here how to perform calculations for such processes.

Answer (score 0):

Gas atoms can be ionized by a variety of ways.  Radio frequency is one of them, and it is faster to have some free electrons created first, but not necessary.  The FCC harmonics reserved for plasma researchers are multiples of 12.5 MHz (hazily recollection - might start at 6.25).  DC in coils can also be used, but is much slower than using AC in coils.  The physical mechanism for AC radio waves is the electron orbits will change shape per the incident angle of the EM waves.  Some small increase in orbital lobe/diameter will result, allowing either the electron to be more easily collided off, or even wiggle off, if the intensity is great enough (it takes time).  As free electrons are created by these processes, the rate of ionization increases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they are using a variation of "cyclotron resonance" heating. This relies on the presence of the electromagnets in the ionization region.

There will be a few free electrons present at first, and by driving the electrons near their orbital cyclotron frequency in a magnetic field, they can be accelerated to higher and higher velocity. Eventually the electrons will have sufficient energy to ionize the gas molecules they collide with, thereby creating even more electrons. So, technically the electrons are doing the ionization.

I believe electron cyclotron resonance ionization sources typically uses microwave frequencies (still not large enough to ionize with a single photon), so this method seems to ionize in a much weaker magnetic field for some reason. I'm also intentionally ignoring any true plasma effects that may be occurring, because plasmas are really complicated.